# pycharm 2016.1.2: font not clear in database view and code priview

Tags: ubuntu, pycharm

I updated pycharm from 5.0.3 to 2016.1.2.
Most functions work fine.
Except the font looks not clear in the database tool and code priview.
Please refer to the attachments.

My OS version: ubuntu-14.04 desktop

[image: Code preview in the scroll bar]
[image: Database view]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this problem by change `Antialiasing` of `Editor` from `Subpixel` to `Greyscale` in `File -> Settings -> Appearance`.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I am helping you, by the way thats what I would do. It's simply changing the theme of the IDE, go to File-> settings, there go to Editor and then Colors and fonts, there change the theme and press accept and you would have changed your writting style. Hope it could help you :D

Comment: I try to change theme or font. The problem remains.